# jQuery multiselect selected based on text

Tags: jquery, text, multi-select, attr, selected

Trying to get the following to work but can't really find what's wrong that prevents the selection to happen.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="inputbox" name="keywords[]" id="keywords">
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="11">Car</option>
<option value="8" selected="selected">Cat</option>
<option value="9">Elephant</option>
<option value="6">Man</option>
<option value="10">Mouse</option>
<option value="1">One person</option>
<option value="2">People</option>
<option value="5">Woman</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="inputbox" value="" id="keywords_new" name="keywords_new">
<a href="#" id="addkeyword">Add keyword</a>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addkeyword').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newkeyword = $('#keywords_new').val();
    var keyselect = $('#keywords');
    keyselect.each(function () {
        alert(newkeyword);
        if ($(this).text() == newkeyword){
                alert(newkeyword);
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected").multiselect("refresh");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Testing on http://jsfiddle.net/SwmN6/58/

Comment: the alert()s are just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keyselect = $('#keywords')
```

Shouldn't be this ?

```
var keyselect = $('#keywords option')
```

Comment: I don't think so. It seems he wants to select the typed keyword.

Comment: @ByScripts - absolutely! That's the missing piece of the puzzle. Thank you! Test on jsfiddle and worked